# scp Authenticates but only gives the Welcome message

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I would like to use passwordless scp

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -P 2022 ~/report.pdf user1@myserver.com:~/
```

but I only get

Welcome user1 to p6.             Wed, 28 Jan 2015 - 14:46 PM EST

I have added the necessary keys and that shows proper authentication. When I do it in verbose mode I get

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host myserver.com, user user1, command scp -v -t ~/
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to myserver.com [X.X.X.X] port 2022.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/morteza/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/morteza/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 65:b1:52:b3:b5:1a:ff:f6:c7:3a:e7:82:dd:e2:16:32
debug1: Host '[myserver.com]:2022' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/morteza/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/morteza/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to myserver.com ([X.X.X.X]:2022).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_US.utf-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_US.utf-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = POSIX
debug1: Sending env LC_MESSAGES = en_US.utf-8
debug1: Sending env LC_COLLATE = en_US.utf-8
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.utf-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_US.utf-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t ~/
Welcome user1 to p6.             Wed, 28 Jan 2015 - 14:42 PM EST
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3480, received 3336 bytes, in 0.7 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 5245.4, received 5028.3
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Any clues what's wrong? looks like no matter what path I give to it in destination machine it doesn't care.

Comment: What is printing that welcome message? A shell init script? If you disable that message does this work?

Comment: I can't disable it. it's not from .bashrc, some linux monitoring library installed on the server generates a welcome message when you do ssh

Comment: Does something like `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -P 2022 user1@myserver.com id` or `.... ls` or some other simple command work correctly? Does sftp? My theory is that the message is screwing `scp` up. I know unexpected output will screw `sftp` up (the question about it before was for confirmation).

Comment: I have experienced with welcome messages screwing ssh, sftp before. I suspect this is again the same thing. BUT I can append the `ls` or `id` commands and get the results.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't sure those would be affected. They work differently. `scp` is a subsystem it might have different requirements. I'm still leaning towards that message being the problem. You could try `-vvv` to see if the higher debug levels tell you anything more.

Comment: Thanks for the edit btw. I noticed for some reason there was some echos in bashrc, got rid of those and got rid of the landscape.canonical.com sever statistics messages. Works like a charm! Here is some useful links:
http://blog.kember.net/articles/removing-landscape-advert-from-ubuntu-login/
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/landscape-canonical-how-do-you-remove-it-4175448599/

Comment: Sounds like you should self-answer then with that information and those links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was the statistics and welcome messages printed in the beginning of an ssh session. The only solution is getting rid of any echo statement in the .bashrc or related files or any scripts that might print some statistics messages lines like the messages printed by landscape.canonical.com in ubuntu.